# random split sparse.lil_matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I am new to Python, I am using following way to store the data in a link list matrix format.

```
>>> from scipy import sparse,random
>>> m = 2
>>> X = [sparse.lil_matrix((5,5)) for i in range(m)]
>>> X[0][0,1] = 1 
>>> X[0][2,3] = 1
>>> X[1][0,4] = 1
>>> X[1][1,4] = 1
>>> X[1][2,4] = 1 
>>> X

    [<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>, <5x5 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>]
```

Is there a way to randomly divide this lil_matrix X as training(75%) and testset(25%)

Answer (score 0):

First, your `X` is a list containing two sparse matrices.

But if I make one sparse matrix, I can select rows from with simple indexing:

```
In [41]: M=sparse.lil_matrix(np.eye(5))

In [42]: M
Out[42]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [43]: M.A
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [44]: M[[0,1,4],:]
Out[44]: 
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [45]: M[[2,3],:]
Out[45]: 
<2x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [46]: M[[2,3],:].A
Out[46]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Row indexing of sparse matrices isn't as fast as with dense arrays, but works, at least for `lil` and `csr` formats.

There's nothing special in the `scipy.sparse` package for splitting a matrix like this.  You'd have to work out the random indexing yourself.

[sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)
handles `Allowed inputs are lists, numpy arrays, scipy-sparse matrices or pandas dataframes.`  Tracing the code, the actual split is done with `utils.safe_indexing(X, indices)` which can handle a variety of `X`.  But it like a `sparse` matrix is indexed as I demonstrated.  It may require a `csr` format rather than `lil`.